# How to install Postgis with Osm2pgsql on NixOS

Tags: postgresql, postgis, nix, nixos

When installing PostGIS on NixOS with an expression like

```
  services.postgresql.extraPlugins = [ (pkgs.postgis.override { postgresql = pkgs.postgresql94; }).v_2_1_4 ];
```

How to add other extensions like Osm2pgsql to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[osm2pgsql](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql) is not yet packaged in nix, so a first step would be to package it.

As far as I see you use `osm2pgsql` tool as a command line utility. Adding it to `environment.systemPackages` should make it available in your $PATH.